# Elastic search : Snapshot not creating

Tags: elasticsearch

I am runnign this command

```
http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/titan_es_backup?pretty
```

**output**

```
{
  "titan_es_backup" : {
    "type" : "fs",
    "settings" : {
      "compress" : "true",
      "location" : "/home/manish/Softwares/DataBackUp/ES"
    }
  }
}
```

again this command

```
http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/titan_es_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=false
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"error":"SnapshotMissingException[[titan_es_backup:snapshot_1] is missing]; nested: FileNotFoundException[/home/manish/Softwares/DataBackUp/ES/snapshot-snapshot_1 (No such file or directory)]; ","status":404}
```

Where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Can you specify the HTTP method (GET, PUT, POST) you used for each command?

Comment: I was simply running the above command in browser