# Attempts to create elasticsearch snapshot result in "SnapshotMissingException"

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I've created a snapshot repo at /_snapshot/my_backup/ (which involved creating directories for everything up to "my_backup" in the exception below) so the next step of creating the actual snapshot should be simple. However, when I run the command `curl -PUT 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true`
I get the result

> {"error":"SnapshotMissingException[[my_backup:snapshot_1] is missing]; nested: FileNotFoundException[/home/ubuntu/backups/my_backup/snapshot-snapshot_1 (No such file or directory)]; ","status":404}

Usually PUT is used on an existing resource, whereas POST creates the actual resource, so I've tried using POST instead, both with and without "snapshot_1" in the url (in the latter case it just returns the same thing as doing a GET on my_backup/_all and does not actually create a snapshot), but keep getting the same exception. The version of elasticsearch I'm running is 1.7.5 and I'm making this snapshot so that I can upgrade.

The only other example I've found of someone having a similar problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669956/elastic-search-snapshot-not-creating), but they weren't using cURL or trying these other methods (and their problem never got solved).

Comment: Even though this seemed like the wrong thing to do, just to experiment I tried running "touch backups/my_backup/snapshot-snapshot_1" to see what would happen if there were no FileNotFoundException. The result is {"error":"ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent]","status":400} and if I use mkdir instead of touch the result is {"error":"SnapshotMissingException[[my_backup:snapshot_1] is missing]; nested: FileNotFoundException[/home/ubuntu/backups/my_backup/snapshot-snapshot_1 (Is a directory)]; ","status":404}

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it should have been `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true`